# Google Rich Snippet with ajax pagination

Tags: javascript, ajax, pagination, rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets

I write an embedded widget which show reviews which uploads dynamically in batches. I would like to use Google Rich Snippets for Reviews not just AggregatedRating.

I'm adding Google Rich Snippets using JSON-LD format dynamycally when I'm lazy loading reviews.

Does Google Crawler work for all reviews on page or is it required any extra features for pagination?

Thanks for any response (resources, books, blogs).

Answer (score 1):

A brief clarification. Google uses a controlled vocabulary defined by `schema.org`. Publishers may present information using schema.org `terms`. If a Publisher uses terms from schema.org, it also must structure the information to conform to the schema.org `grammar`. For example, for your `Reviews`, terms for `AggregateRating` must be allowable and complete (Google requires specific data). When a Publisher presents structured information, it may expose the data to humans on a web page using `Microdata` (Rich Snippets) or `RDFa`. If the Publisher has correctly used the schema.org terms and grammar, the Google Crawler will parse and correctly interpret the information.

Publisher also may present information in a machine-readable format. That format is `JSON-LD`. The JSON-LD structure could package a collection of Reviews on a single page. Publisher will want to make sure that the meaning of the JSON-LD structure has the same meaning as the HTML markup (either Microdata or RDFa). Google may marginalize a site where human-readable data is not semantically equivalent to machine-readable data.

You ask about "extra features" for pagination. The JSON-LD can be packaged as a single structure to describe all semantic information on a page. That structure may be anywhere in the HTML document. If you chunk your Reviews in some order on the page, the RDFa or Microdata will be associated with the chunks. Otherwise, I'm not use what you mean by pagination. You ask: "Does Google Crawler work for all reviews on a page?" The answer is yes.

Comment: Under pagination I mean 2 types of pagination (infinite scroll with dynamically added data and simple paged area with replaced content on changing page). I bother is it enough just added JSON-LD for every batch dynamically or I will just get Google Rich snippets searchable for the  first batch. Thanks for explanation.

Comment: You will need to update your single JSON-LD structure with each new batch. Pagination will have no effect WRT the JSON-LD structure. If you use Microdata or RDFa, you will want to add new markup to each new batch. Google will processes the new data, particularly if you add schema.org terms for date modification (if you use JSON-LD follow the same process there). You may wish to update your sitemap to indicate when a change occurred (i.e. a new batch). A "belts-and-braces" strategy never hurts and may help Google crawlers.

Comment: The problem is that I'm working with embedded widget (not site, just clarifiaction). I have several questions. 1)Should I have single script tag with array of entities if I want to past multiple Reviews for example? (Is multiple script tags forbidden (in case, infinite pagination when we can add each review with own script tag), I don't see any limitation) 2) Would it helpful for Google Crawler to append for single JSON-LD script new entity just when user do first click on several pages page? (we always show 1 page, and user click  e.g. 3 and 5 pages, we append 2 extra batches)

Comment: How Google Crawler will track reviews on other pages (except 1, 3, 5)?

Comment: I don't completely understand your scenario and need to see examples before offering more specific advice. However, in general, I recommend a single JSON-LD structure for each page. For the JSON-LD process, logically separate the idea of a user action (a click) from the data structure. If a link navigates a user to a new page, then the items on that page should be in JSON-LD . The corollary is true. If you did *not* use JSON-LD for semantic information, you would have to use either Microdata or RDFa. That mark-up *must be* on the same page (as it's part of HTML markup) as the new item.